# How to build a simple multi device chat application?

Tags: android, network-programming

I already knew the basic of android programming. now I want to build a offline multi-user chat application. I found peer-to-peer and Bluetooth are the most used techniques to communicate each other. I need to know,

1. Which one is easy to begin with among P2P and Bluetooth?
2. I already built a Bluetooth chat application using online tutorial. That method is a communicating between two endpoints. Is it possible to make it more than two?

Comment: I marked the question as primarily opinion based and the question is not suitable for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which one is easy to begin with among P2P and Bluetooth?

It depends on your previous skill and expertise. As I have seen that you have already managed to create an application for p2p communication via bluetooth, so of course it is easy to begin with bluetooth.

> I already built a Bluetooth chat application using online tutorial.
>   That method is a communicating between two endpoints. Is it possible
>   to make it more than two?

Yes, it is possible. There are a lot of tutorials in the internet of connecting multiple bluetooth devices. Please check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963614/android-bluetooth-chat-sample-app-multiple-connections).

However, chat application based on bluetooth is not a good approach. If this for your learning only, then from my point of view this is fine. If this is a professional project, then I would suggest you might consider looking into other options. Check [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-android-chat-app-using-firebase--cms-27397) which uses Firebase as well. Using firebase for real time chat application will definitely serve your purpose.